# Android - Position Relative layout within main layout Dynamicaly

Tags: java, android, xml, android-relativelayout

I am trying to add  Relative Layout to my mainLayout (which is also a relative layout) dynamically. I have it so that you can add the layout multiple times by clicking a button. But I want it so that the first layout added is on the leftside of the screen, the second layout is in the middle and the thirs layout is on the right, etc... I did this using the modulus operator but it isnt working.

Below is my code

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
RelativeLayout rlcopy;
RelativeLayout[] rArray = new RelativeLayout[20];
int counter = 1;
RelativeLayout llcustomrow;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams; 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.customworkout, container, false);

    llcustomrow = (RelativeLayout)mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.llcustomrow);

    for(int i = 1;i<rArray.length-1;i++){
        rArray[i] = (RelativeLayout)View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.addworkoutlayout, null); 

        if(i%3 == 1 ){
            rArray[i].setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        }else if(i%3 == 2){
            rArray[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        }else{
            rArray[i].setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }

    }

    Button bAdd = (Button) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.bAddExcercise);



    bAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             llcustomrow.addView(rArray[counter]);  
             counter++;
        }
    });


    return mLinearLayout;
}
```

I believe the problem is where i am setting the gravity, I do not think it is doing anything

Comment: You're not adding the `rArray[i]` to a parent view.

Comment: Also method `setGravity` sets the content gravity within a view/viewgroup, it doesn't specify the gravity that is should take within a parent viewgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you want to use the fragments for these purposes? You can use three frames with weight 1, for example, in LinearLayout with horizontal orientation in your main layout file. Then create three layouts for each frame. For dynamic work with previous you can use FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction. Read about them please.